# JSF "rendered" - strange behavior

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I can't explaine this well - it's need to see:
[Video screencast](http://youtu.be/4jRSyBqa7HY)

Please explain me what happens?

next code work and return true or false but when I put this to rendered="" this not work.

```
#{!empty detailsBean.goods.pictures}
```

rendered="true" rendered="false" rendered="#{true}" - work

```
<p:commandButton id="btn_details" value="#{msg.btn_details}" oncomplete="PF('dlg-detailed').show()" update=":dlg-detailed-id">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{detailsBean.goods}" value="#{goods}" />
    <f:param name="id" value="#{goods.id}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

Dialog - where I try render text with condition.

```
<p:dialog id="dlg-detailed-id" widgetVar="dlg-detailed" header="#{msg.btn_details}" dynamic="true" modal="true" draggable="false" width="800" height="600">
    <h:outputText value="Some Text For Rendering" rendered="#{!empty detailsBean.goods.pictures}" />
</p:dialog>
```

Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1
JBoss AS 7.1.1

I apologize for my mistakes in English

Comment: impossible to understand the question :(

Comment: why when I put rendered="#{!empty detailsBean.goods.pictures}" to <h:outputText tag - all stop working - I have no error messages - but #{!empty detailsBean.goods.pictures} work, and if collection not empty return true. I use rendered="#{... in another page - and on another page this attribute work good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case, solution is: add < h:form> tag and then rendered="#{!empty detailsBean.goods.pictures}" work

```
<h:form id="form-detailed" >
    <p:dialog id="dlg-detailed-id" widgetVar="dlg-detailed" header="#{msg.btn_details}" dynamic="true" modal="true" draggable="false" width="800" height="600">
        <h:outputText value="Some Text For Rendering" rendered="#{!empty detailsBean.goods.pictures}" />
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```